# Package management on Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx, yum, apt, package-management

Can anyone recommend a package management tool like apt-get or yum for Mac OS X?  I've seen that [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) has ported apt-get to Mac OS X, is this a good way to go, or are there other/better options out there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three more well known package management applications for Mac OS X:

- [Fink](http://finkproject.org) that you mentioned.
- [MacPorts](http://macports.org) which is hosted with Apple's Open Source Projects (eg. CalendarServer) and tends to have the largest and most up to date collection of packages.
- [Homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) which is relatively recent and has a much smaller set of packages.

Comment: I am new to OSX as well. What's the newest status updates on all these package management tools?

Answer (score 2):

Try [mac ports](http://www.macports.org/) it has a great repository of applications ready to go for your mac.

Answer (score 2):

not exactly "package management" in the same sense as *NIX package management, but [AppFresh](http://metaquark.de/appfresh/) has made my life much much easier. I also use MacPorts for adding *NIX tools.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [pkgsrc](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/platforms.html#darwin) from NetBSD available for Mac OS X, but I found it less stable than MacPorts.

Coming from a BSD world I prefer MacPorts over Fink, but if you are a friend of debian you might be best suited with Fink.

Still have to try HomeBrew myself, but the concept that it re-uses existing components from my OS X base has kept from from it until now. I don't share Apple's policy regarding versioning of third party components.